# Put words from mysql db in order

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make a "put words in order" php script from data stored in mysql but I have no clue in how to start. Could someone help me? I just need to separate each word in order to the person could select the word, not type.
Like any of this: 
http://a4esl.org/q/j/ck/wo-01.html 
http://baladre.info/english/sedaviwebfront/pastSimporder1.htm

 Thank you for the attention and help!

@chris85 I'm new in this php programing thing.
I could kind of make this script, sorry maybe for the bad "programming" but it is working:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "questions";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if (isset($_POST["topic"])) {
    $topic = $_POST["topic"];
    $subjectid = $_POST["subjectid"];
} else {
    $row['topicid'] = $_GET["id"];
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Questions</title>
</head>

<body>
Question: <br><br>
<form action="questions.php" method="post">
<?

if (isset($_POST["topic"])) {
    $sql = "SELECT topicid FROM topic WHERE topic=\"$topic\" AND subjectid=\"$subjectid\"";
    $id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($id);
}


$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE topicid=\"$row[topicid]\" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<font size=\"6\"><b>".$row2['question']."</b></font>"; ?>
</form>

<? 
if ($row2['check'] == "0"){
    echo "Level 0: Try to memorize and type the answer according with the text bellow";
} elseif  ($row2['check'] == "1"){
    echo "Level 1: Try to type the answer by looking the begining of it, if you can't remember go back to level 1 by clicking in \"I got it wrong!\"";
}elseif  ($row2['check'] == "2"){
    echo "Level 2: Try to type the answer without looking at any part of it, if you forget a simple part you can give a little look";
}elseif  ($row2['check'] == "3"){
    echo "Level 3: Type the answer without realy looking at any part of it, anyways you still having the color hint";
}elseif  ($row2['check'] == "4"){
    echo "Level 4: Type the answer without any hint. Now when you will just be able the hit the button \"I got it right!\" when the answer be completely right, if you want you may go back to <b>level 3</b> by presing \"I got ir wrong!\"";
}elseif  ($row2['check'] == "5"){
    echo "Level 5: Congrats: you got it, fell free to repeat as many times you want! Now you don't need to type exactly as the answer, for it you will have the buttons bellow to check if your answer is right. Just be honest! =D";
}
    ?> 
<!-- start -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<?
 echo "<textarea name=\"password\" id=\"password\"  hidden='1'>" . $row2['answer']. "</textarea>";
 ?>
</label>
<br>
<label>Answer: <br />
  <textarea name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" style="width: 80%; height: 100px; font-size:20px" /></textarea> <span id='message'></span>

<? if  ($row2['check'] <= "3"){
    echo "<script>
$('#confirm_password, #password').on('input', function(e){
  changeColor($('#confirm_password').val(), $('#password').val());
});

function changeColor(c, p){
  var color;
  if(c === p){
    color = 'green';
  } else if(p.indexOf(c) === 0 && c != ''){
    color = 'yellow';
  } else {
    color = 'red';
  }
  $('#confirm_password').css('background-color', color);
}
</script>"; }

if  ($row2['check'] == "4"){
echo "<script>

$('#confirm_password, #password').on('input', function(e){
  changeColor($('#confirm_password').val(), $('#password').val());
});

function changeColor(c, p){
  var color;
  if(c === p){
    color = 'visible';
  } else {
    color = 'hidden';
  }
  $('#certo').css('visibility', color);
}

</script>"; }
 ?>
<!-- end --><br><br>
<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <? echo "<td width=\"33.3%\"><form action=\"right.php\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"topicid\" value=\"" . $row['topicid']. "\"></input><input name=\"questionid\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $row2['questionid']. "\"></input>";
      if  ($row2['check'] == "5"){ echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ncomp\" value=\"1\"></input>"; }
      echo"<input name=\"certo\" id=\"certo\" type=\"submit\" value=\"I got it Right!\"";
      if  ($row2['check'] == "4"){ echo "style=\"width:500px; visibility:hidden\""; } else { echo "style=\"width:500px\""; } 
      echo"></form></td>";
   echo "<td align=\"center\" width=\"33.3%\"><a align=\"center\" href='questions.php?id=".$row['topicid']."'>Skip</a></td>"; 
   echo "   <td width=\"33.3%\"><form action=\"wrong.php\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"topicid\" value=\"" . $row['topicid']. "\"></input><input name=\"questionid\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $row2['questionid']. "\"></input><input type=\"submit\" value=\"I got it Wrong!\" style=\"width:500px;\"></form></td>"; ?> </div>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<?
echo "<br><br>
<form action=\"aquestion.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"topicid\" value=\"" . $row['topicid']. "\"></input>";  ?>
<input type="submit" value="New Text Question"></input>
</form>

<br><br><br>
Show answer: 
<script type="text/javascript">

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}

</script><? if  ($row2['check'] >= "3" && $row2['check'] <= "4"){ echo"<div id=level style=\"visibility:hidden\">"; } ?>
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck" > No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"><br>
    <div id="ifYes" <? if ($row2['check'] >= "2"){ echo "style=\"visibility:hidden\"";} else  ?> >
      <textarea type='text' id='yes' name='yes' <? if ($row2['check'] == "0"){ echo "style=\"width:80%; height:100px\""; }?> ><?php echo $row2['answer']; ?></textarea><br>
    </div><? if  ($row2['check'] >= "3" && $row2['check'] <= "4"){ echo "</div>"; } ?>


</body>
</html>
```

What I would like is, to put the scramble words thing at the "level 1"

Comment: Can you provide an example here of what you have and what you want? Also showing what you have tried would be useful.

Comment: For Stack Overflow too broad this question is.

Comment: Incidentally, the order of words in English is for the most part irrelevant. By convention we tend to use 'subject, predicate, rest of sentence', but inversions are common, and perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Too broad for SO perhaps, but not,, by the sound of it, for Yoda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to put the selected (clicked) text into a variable and add it to the previous selected text in a div with an ID - for example "answer_div". One textbox given as an example but it could be a div and you would then need to get its innerHTML instead.

You could also have a hidden input with a name and an ID and use `getElementById()` to put the completed sentence into that in your function so it can be submitted to PHP.

You seem to have managed to get your words displayed in the text boxes so you would need to add an `onClick;` function and pass `this` to it:

```
    <html> 
        <head>
        <script language=JavaScript>
        var answer_var = '';
        var elem = '';

        function add_answers(elem){   
        answer_var = elem.value+" ";
        document.getElementById('answer_div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('answer_div').innerHTML + answer_var; 
        }
        </script>
        </head>
          <body>
           <input type ="text" id="answer_var" value="word" onclick="add_answers(this);" />
           <div id="answer_div"></div>
          </body>
        </html>
```